# (Fixed)How to find just one String value on a dynamic array(File, Stream, Buffer)?

Tags: java, arrays

My little project is about adding new numbers to a dynamic array thanks to a do while and a switch. My problem is that when I want to search for a String value that exists in the array, it omits it completely in the if. Problem is in third case if condition

```
package savearray;

import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class SaveArray {

    public static int op, xWhile, nArray, array[], accumulator;
    public static String strArray, strSeeNumber, newStringArray[];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            System.out.println("-----------------------------");
            System.out.println("1: Add numbers | 2: Read numbers | 3: See existing number");
            System.out.println("-----------------------------");
            op = in.nextInt();
            switch (op) {

                case 1:
                    xWhile = 1;
                    accumulator++;
                    System.out.println("Size of the array:");
                    nArray = in.nextInt();
                    array = new int[nArray];
                    try {
                        for (int i = 0; i < nArray; i++) {
                            System.out.println("Enter the desired number");
                            array[i] = in.nextInt();
                        }
                         // Accumulator for when the operation is done more than 1 time, the array will not be null at the beginning, and when it is run a second time or more, don't override the strArray and act like a database, saving values until the program ends.
                        if (accumulator == 1) {
                            strArray = "";
                        }
                        for (int i : array) {
                            strArray += "[" + i + "]";
                        }
                        //Save array
                        FileOutputStream saveFile = new FileOutputStream("DB.txt");
                        OutputStreamWriter outWrite = new OutputStreamWriter(saveFile);
                        outWrite.write(strArray);
                        outWrite.flush();
                        outWrite.close();
                        saveFile.close();
                        System.out.println("File saved.");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                    }
                    break;

                case 2:
                    xWhile = 1;
                    try {
                        //Open array
                        FileInputStream saveFile = new FileInputStream("DB.txt");
                        InputStreamReader inReader = new InputStreamReader(saveFile);
                        BufferedReader buffRead = new BufferedReader(inReader);
                        String strArray = buffRead.readLine();
                        buffRead.close();
                        inReader.close();
                        saveFile.close();

                        //Print array
                        newStringArray = strArray.split(",");
                        for (String i : newStringArray) {
                            System.out.println(i);
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                    }
                    break;

                case 3:
                    xWhile = 1;
                    in.skip("\n");
                    System.out.println("Input the number:");
                    strSeeNumber = in.nextLine();
                    for (String newStringArray1 : newStringArray) {
                        //The problem is here:
                        if (newStringArray1.equals(strSeeNumber)) {
                            System.out.print("[" + newStringArray1 + "]");
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Number not found, find an existing number again.");
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    xWhile = 0;
                    break;
            }
        } while (xWhile == 1);
    }
}
```

So I think my problem is that I was comparing a string value in a text file, I hope that sounds logical hahaha, so to fix it and find the exact number you want to find you should use Pattern and Matcher (or whatever solution you have experienced):

```
package savearray;

import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class SaveArray {

public static int op, xWhile, nArray, array[], accumulator;
public static String strArray, strSeeN, newStringArray[];

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    do {
        System.out.println("-----------------------------");
        System.out.println("1: Add numbers | 2: Read numbers | 3: See existing number");
        System.out.println("-----------------------------");
        op = in.nextInt();
        switch (op) {

            case 1:
                xWhile = 1;
                accumulator;++;
                System.out.println("Size of the array");
                nArray = in.nextInt();
                array = new int[nArray];
                try {
                    for (int i = 0; i < nArray; i++) {
                        System.out.println("Enter the desired number");
                        array[i] = in.nextInt();
                    }
                    // Accumulator for when the operation is done more than 1 time, the array will not be null at the beginning, and when it is run a second time or more, don't override the strArray and act like a database, saving values until the program ends.
                    if (accumulator; == 1) {
                        strArray = "";
                    }
                    for (int i : array) {
                        strArray += "[" + i + "]";
                    }
                    //Save array
                    FileOutputStream saveFile = new FileOutputStream("DB.txt");
                    OutputStreamWriter outWrite = new OutputStreamWriter(saveFile);
                    outWrite.write(strArray);
                    outWrite.flush();
                    outWrite.close();
                    saveFile.close();
                    System.out.println("File saved.");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
                break;

            case 2:
                xWhile = 1;
                try {
                    //Open array
                    FileInputStream saveFile = new FileInputStream("DB.txt");
                    InputStreamReader inReader = new InputStreamReader(saveFile);
                    BufferedReader buffRead = new BufferedReader(inReader);
                    String strArray = buffRead.readLine();
                    buffRead.close();
                    inReader.close();
                    saveFile.close();

                    //Print array
                    newStringArray = strArray.split(",");
                    for (String i : newStringArray) {
                        System.out.println(i);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
                break;

            case 3:
                xWhile = 1;
                in.skip("\n");
                System.out.println("Enter the number:");
                strSeeN = in.nextLine();
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(strSeeN);
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(strArray);
                while (matcher.find()) {
                    System.out.println("Number found: " + matcher.group());
                }
                break;

            default:
                xWhile = 0;
                break;
        }
    } while (xWhile == 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting "number not found find an existing number again"??

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's really quite unclear what you are asking. The line "when I want to search for a String value that exists in the array, it omits it completely in the if" is pretty ambiguous. Which `if` do you mean? Perhaps if you just posted the code with the issue it'd make it easier to help.

Comment: I recommend that you do not catch any exceptions - at least until you have the code working properly.

Comment: @Supercool. Yes, it is actually a bit confusing since it should go into that if and print only the String that I am looking for and exists in the array.

Comment: @sprinter. Sorry the post is already updated and corrected by Supercool, and about the exceptions I'm a little noob about that :/, but if I remove the catch(IOException e){}, it gives me an error on the try{}

Comment: @Yourdead I meant to remove the `try` block entirely - just let your code throw an exception so you know what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because there are no elements in **newStringArray** and it will throw you a null pointer exception if you directly selection option 1 and in second time you select option 3.You **forgot** to read your content from file.Try **reading** it and compare. and also when writing to file append a **comma** to value otherwise **split** wont work.

```
int index=0;
 for (int i : array) {
  if(index==nArray-1)
  strArray += "[" + i + "]";
  else
  strArray += "[" + i + "],";
  index++;
 }
```

Modify the following in your case 3

```
System.out.println("Input the number:");
strSeeNumber = in.nextLine();
try{
ileInputStream saveFile = new FileInputStream("DB.txt");
InputStreamReader inReader = new InputStreamReader(saveFile);
BufferedReader buffRead = new BufferedReader(inReader);
String strArray = buffRead.readLine();
buffRead.close();
inReader.close();
saveFile.close();//Print array
System.out.println(strArray);
newStringArray = strArray.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "").replaceAll("\\s", "").split(",");
for (String newStringArray1 : newStringArray) {
    System.out.println(newStringArray1);
   if (newStringArray1.equals(strSeeNumber)) {
    System.out.println("Found Number -[" + newStringArray1 + "]");
} else {
    System.out.println("Number not found, find an existing number again.");
}
}
```

Test your code here - its working :https://onlinegdb.com/rJ5LhsC8L

Comment: Wow, you are a genius, the good thing is that the array found the number, but if I add more numbers and I try to find them, it shows number not found. But I think I can continue from here, thank you!

Comment: Hey if you found the answer correct please upvote and mark it as correct so that other users who have the same problem will know the answer

Comment: Actually, now it's kinda working so far, I have a solution by using Pattern and Matcher lol, to read and extract the number from the text.